# Spree generic implementation for api token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, spree, spree-auth-devise

I an deleting items from spree cart using the following spree api url

`/api/orders/#{current_order.number}/line_items/#{line_iem.id}?line_item[variant_id]=#{line_item.variant.id}&line_item[quantity]=0&token=MyToken`

the token used here is of a single user. I want to implement this in generic way so that it can be used for both guest and registered user.. is it possible?

any help would be highly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create an order using the Spree API, you get an `order_token` in the response. From the [Spree API Guide](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/orders.html):

> The order_token parameter will work for authorizing any action for an order within Spree’s API.

So instead of appending `&token=...` you should append `&order_token=...`

It will work for both registered users as well as guests.

Comment: but i am using this link in ajax in my spree web app. how can I get the value of order token ?

Comment: Ok. You did not mention that in your question. Can you please show some more context/code around the url in your question. Specifically, I am interested in knowing where are you getting the "current_order" from.

Comment: Actually i was implementing cart side bar from which user can update or delete items directly. i am simply using current_order.guest_token