# Spree API use on frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, e-commerce, spree

I want to use spree api on frontend to implement the ajax products search just like the one in orders/edit on backend where you enter 4 characters and it uses api to get variants.

But I am confused about the token. how can i use the following on frontend even when the user is not logged in.

```
/api/variants?q[product_name_or_sku_cont]=product&token=sometoken
```

I had a similar problem with updating cart using api (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285209/spree-generic-implementation-for-api-token/32295729#32295729)) but i solved that using `order_token=current_order.guest_token`

but here i want to implement a search and when a new user visits the site current_order is empty.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this API end point without appending any token at all? A token should not be needed here.

Answer (score 0):

I have change `Spree::Api::Config[:requires_authentication]` to false and now i am able to access it without a token